# dart, reflection symbols from strings

Tags: reflection, dart

When you deploy a dart app so the code is minified, will the following code still work? as I read that strings are maintained but all symbols are minified, so how will the symbol in the invoke method call be created properly if the method name is minified but the string is left as 'sayHi'?

```
import 'dart:mirrors';


void main() {

  var inst = new MyClass(33);

  var instMirror = reflect(inst);

  var res = instMirror.invoke(new Symbol('sayHi'), []).reflectee;

}


class MyClass{

  int x;

  MyClass(this.x);

  int sayHi(){
    print('this class has x = $x');
    return x;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the symbol as a constant as either const Symbol('sayHi') or the shorter #sayHi. That will be minified to match the minified method name. It's possible that new Symbol() with a constant argument might also get minified. Obviously new Symbol with a dynamic argument won't.